# Download and install Android studio gradle offline

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been having internet issues, so installing gradle for android studio has been a big issue, so I downloaded the zip file. However, I dont know how to install it offline and set Android studio to use the offline version. I need help.

[image]

Comment: which android studio version u can use ?

Comment: Android studio 3

Comment: ok then follow my answer.. and if you have any query then ask me. :) @DavidEssien

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- 1st open below link and download the latest `complete` version of Gradle

  https://gradle.org/releases/

Now you find your path where your android studio install

then Find **.gradle** folder, normally gradle is present here...

```
C:\Users\**YourAccountFolder**\.gradle\wrapper\dists\
```

Now paste your .zip file in dists folder and Extract.

Now open android Studio Go to

> File > Settings > Build, Execute, Deployment > Gradle >

Now in Dialog select **Use Local gradle distribution** and paste path of your folder where extract .zip file.

then apply and OK

now you can update your **`gradle(app)`** And Go to file, setting same as like above path and in dialog SELECT **Offline work**

Apply and Ok.

Comment: I have done all this android studio is still going online to check for gradle and when I turn off the internet, it comes up with an error. The problem is that even online, the download is never successful

Comment: your **Service Directory path** is wrong ... @DavidEssien

Comment: set your service directory path like : **home/davldshare/.gradle** @DavidEssien

Comment: here is the error it produces:    "Gradle sync failed: Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.2): No cached version available for offline mode
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (46s 480ms)"

Comment: so Go to the settings and unchecked **Offline Mode**  and sync gradle or run project for 1st time if is successfully run then you can go in settings and checked **Offline Mode** @DavidEssien

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad. That's what I'm doing now. Just that internet service here is terrible. It keeps stopping half way. That's why I was particular about offline. I'm hoping it works.

Comment: look only unchecked offline mode nothing to change other settings @DavidEssien

Answer (score 18):

- Download gradle zip file
- Open the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file from your android project, path specified below

> my-app\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

- Set the `distributionUrl` to point to the download zip location, for example

> distributionUrl=file:///C:/Users/username/Downloads/Compressed/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

Done!

Now build the project and Android Studio will install the gradle.

Comment: Worked for me,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In June 2021 im using Android Studio 4.2.1 and I could enable gradle offline mode using the method outlined in the docs below.

[image: Instructions Image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#3.6-gradle-offline-ui