# How to use offline gradle distribution instead of wrapper in latest Intellij/Android Studio "For new projects"?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, offline

As of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291289/download-and-install-android-studio-gradle-offline), I was able to specify gradle distribution for offline "existing" project builds by downloading latest version from https://gradle.org/releases/ and specifyinng them inside the Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle

> But for opening settings for new projects I've no option to configure
>   them. I got this screen when I open the Gradle settings for new projects.
>   There is no option to configure "Use gradle from":

[image]

**Downloading gradle for every new project of around 150 MB is not very feasible.**

So how do i specify the offline gradle distribution for new projects?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215792